# What is the resistance of a single human cell?

Tags: electrophysiology

What is the resistance of a single human cell? I know different cells will have different values, some examples would suffice. I did not find any such information on the internet.

Comment: At what voltage? Not only does this differ by cell (and environment), it often varies by voltage (and time due to inactivation).

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please insert the term "electrical" in your title and question to make it clear what you are talking about. It would also be a good idea as a new user for you to complete the tour, your lack of the badge for that implies you have not.

Comment: Hi poi. Welcome to Bio.SE. Please clarify which type of resistance you are referring to. Also, we ask that you demonstrate some previous effort on your own part to have answered your own question. Please provide such support. Thanks.